# The non-differentiability of the Weierstrass function at integers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I came across the following problem while studying series of functions:

> Prove that $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^n x)}{2^n}$ is not differentiable at integers.

I am aware that this series is commonly known as the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), and according to Hardy's famous work in 1916 [Hardy's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989005), it is a typical example of a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. I also found a method in another article by Jon Johnsen https://zhangyk8.github.io/teaching/file/Con_nowhere_diff.pdf that is proven using Fourier analysis. But this homework question comes before the content on Fourier analysis, and the teacher does not recommend using the Fourier analysis method.

It appears that this problem may be a specific case of $a=1/2, b=2$, as mentioned on page 309 of Hardy's paper.

[image]

However, I am still struggling to understand how the application of Lemma 2.12 in that paper leads to the final conclusion that $f(x)$ cannot possess a finite differential coefficient.

[image]

It seems that I need to prove that for an integer $x$, the limit
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2^ny}\cos 2^nx
$$
does not exist. (The sine function utilized in equation (2.34) of Hardy's paper is proposed to be substituted with the cosine function in the current investigation.) Yet, I am unsure of how to approach this.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to complete Hardy's proof? Or is there another elementary method to directly prove the initial question? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: if it helps, from $S(x) = \sin x + S(2x)/2$ you'll get that the derivative at $x=0$ cannot exist

Comment: 1) [Hardy's proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1916-017-03/S0002-9947-1916-1501044-1/S0002-9947-1916-1501044-1.pdf) doesn't seem to "involve the use of Fourier" analysis. 2) Integer values for $x$ have nothing special w.r.t. your function $S(x)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your comments. I have revisited Hardy's proof and realized that this particular case falls under the case where $ab=1$, as mentioned on page 309 of his paper. However, I am still unable to comprehend how applying Lemma 2.12 leads to the final conclusion that $f(x)$ cannot have a finite differential coefficient. Could you kindly provide me with some hints?

Comment: I promise to try to understand it, not to succeed. Meanwhile, since your initial question has changed from "elementary proof *at integers*" (which, as commented, shouldn't be expected) to "some step of Hardy's proof", may I suggest you edit your post accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, but I was mainly suggesting to remove your mention of integers. Again: 1) Hardy's proof didn't use Fourier analysis (and neither does Johnsen's. He only reformulate it in those terms afterwards, when generalizing it). 2) You shouldn't expect a simpler proof of non differentiability of your $S$ *at integers*, which have nothing special with respect to $\sin$ (whose period is $2\pi$, not $1$).

Comment: See Hardy's lemma 2.15.The only useful property of integers w.r.t. your $S$ is that they are not of the form $\frac p{2^q}\pi$ with $p,q$ integers, so that $\sin(2^nx)$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is lunacary series, power series or Fourier series, whose coefficients are zero almost all except for a subseries with distances growing exponentially. The proof of continuity by a dominant series is easy, the proof of non.differentiabilty is difficult, resting on the fact, that any series convergent to x produces series of values, oscillating  by the order of the basic oscillating function used.

By a first search, there is an elaborated PDF [seminar article](http://www.matha.rwth-aachen.de/de/lehre/ws07/sfouana/Aaron_Klueppelberg.pdf)  at RWTH Aachen in German. It's easy by google translate to produce an English version.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function is helpful for understanding the phenomenon of the construction of analytic functions, convergent in the unit disc, nowhere continuous on the unit circle, and therefore having no analytic continuation beyond their primary domain of holomorphy.

Comment: Imo, this does not answer the (quite precise) question.